# Parse -Android Getting multiple push notifications

Tags: java, android, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to send push notifications to Android devices,

When I push a message from parse I get 7 push notifications on a single device.

How can I fix this?

```
    PushService.subscribe(cont, "Abc", ParseActivity.class);
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(cont, Menu.class);
```

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is late response but this may be helpful other one. The Parse library update solve this issue.

Comment: ill upgrade to new one and check

Comment: everytime i m getting two notifications whats the issue can someone tell me @Mayur Raval

Comment: @Erum . can you confirm that parse table contain double entry of your device ? yes  or not ? if yes than go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294181/android-parse-push-notification-device-registration-only-one-time-on-one-device

Comment: use latest library . if you don't @Erum