# Android Parse Push notification device registration only one time on one device

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, devicetoken

Every one I am using the parse service for push notification in my app. but it register all time when i re-install the app in one device.Then problem is that,one device receive multiple notifications on each.  I have done some code for registration which is shown below. please help me,thanks in advance.

```
Parse.initialize(this, PARSE_APP_ID, PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId();
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

And for subscribe:

```
PushService.subscribe(this, userName, Detail.class);
```

In Manifest

Above

```
  <permission
    android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

In application tag:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="act" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.app.example.PushReceiver" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="act" />
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="act" />
            <category android:name="com.example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And each time when I am Install, it show error which is shown below.

```
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709): Failed to run command.
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709): com.parse.ParseException: at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified in this operation
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.ParseCommand$3.then(ParseCommand.java:348)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:452)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:68)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:448)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:322)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:333)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:385)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$8.then(Task.java:1)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:485)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:68)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:481)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.access$9(Task.java:477)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:350)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:1)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:514)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.access$5(Task.java:510)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at   com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:569)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:603)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:497)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:1)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:452)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:68)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:448)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.access$8(Task.java:444)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:315)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$6.then(Task.java:1)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:514)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.access$5(Task.java:510)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:569)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:603)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:497)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$11$1.then(Task.java:1)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$10.run(Task.java:452)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:68)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:448)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:322)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.continueWith(Task.java:333)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$11.run(Task.java:489)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$1.execute(Task.java:68)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:481)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.access$9(Task.java:477)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:350)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$7.then(Task.java:1)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:514)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task.access$5(Task.java:510)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(Task.java:569)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$TaskCompletionSource.setResult(Task.java:603)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at com.parse.Task$3.run(Task.java:228)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-10 12:18:48.555: E/ParseCommandCache(12709):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I want to register only one time for on device. there should be not an issue if app installed multiple time in device.please help me, thanks in advance.

In my case samsung tab 3 registers twice with same UniqueId. Is UniqueId is marked as unique column in parse db? Or we should make it unique? if yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it after update the table with the send of unique id of the android device.

```
 String  android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);         
    Log.e("LOG","android id >>" + android_id);

    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("installationId",android_id);

    installation.saveInBackground();
```

It will update the raw ,but it doesn't re-register the device .

Comment: It is creating new row with same UniqueId

Comment: installationId is a read only field. Only way to update that field is to use CloudCode and use the master key.

Comment: Not working for me either: Getting error: "Cannot modify `installationId` property of an _Installation object."

Answer (score 8):

I think Mukul has provided great cloud code for this issue

here it is

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo("owner", request.user);
query.equalTo("uniqueID", request.object.get("uniqueID"));
query.first().then(function(duplicate) {
    if (typeof duplicate === "undefined") {
        console.log("Duplicate does not exist,New installation");
        response.success();
    } else {
        console.log("Duplicate exist..Trying to delete " + duplicate.id);
        duplicate.destroy().then(function(duplicate) {
            console.log("Successfully deleted duplicate");
            response.success();
        }, function() {
            console.log(error.code + " " + error.message);
            response.success();
        });

    }
}, function(error) {
    console.warn(error.code + error.message);
    response.success();
});
});
```

Note that owner is the username or the primary key that you think u can use.

here's the link of the same with better explanation by mukul
https://www.parse.com/questions/check-for-duplicate-installations-of-same-user-on-re-installation-of-app

Comment: By this way, duplicate object got deleted, but then I was not able to get channels of it ?? How to persist channel of that installation ?

Comment: @PalakDarji  That totally depends on what structure you have used. What i do is keeping installation object reference in user class, and whenever the new installation Id is created  before deleting the duplicate Id i copy all the user saved data from duplicate installation obj to current installation obj .. i.e. except replacing the parse auto created token , androidId , installation id...... i replace it with the duplicate entries .. hope u got it what i am trying to convey ..its tidious but i have made a module such that I am using it now for all the projects

Answer (score 7):

`PushService.subscribe` seems to cache the subscription in local storage, to avoid re-subscribing when you launch the app multiple times.

This is what the first parameter of that method is used for :

> context - This is used to access local storage to cache the
>   subscription, so it must currently
>             be a viable context.

(quote from [here](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html)).

However, when you uninstall the app, local storage for that app is wiped from your device, so the new installation will cause `PushService.subscribe` to re-register to Google Cloud Messaging. If the new registration returns a new registration ID, Parse would have two registration IDs that can be used to send push notifications to your app, and both of them would be linked to the same userName you supplied to `subscribe`. Therefore sending a notification to that userName will send it to both registration IDs, causing it to arrive twice.

When Parse send the notifications for you, they should get from Google a response with `canonical_registration_id`, which will let them know one of the registration IDs associated with your app on your device is old, and should not be used anymore. Therefore (assuming Parse have a decent implementation of GCM) the next time you send a notification to your device, you should receive it only once.

Comment: I have the same problem I get this error and I do not register "objectID" with the channel. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue. I sort of solved it by calling the below method in my Activity's `onCreate()`

```
/**
     * Initialize Push Messaging Service and subscribe to all-users channel
     */
    private void initParsePushMessaging() {
        ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation
                .getCurrentInstallation();
        //You might skip this if
        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            parseInstallation.put("user",
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        }
        if (parseInstallation.getObjectId() != null)
            parseInstallation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(),"channel_name",
                            MainHomeActivity.class);
                }
            });

    }
```

Even though it didn't completely solve my problem but now my app doesn't hang and no more ANR's due to this Parse implementation. If i re install an app and run it now then the app creates a new installation record and remove's the last one. The only problem is that the **channel_name** is **not subscribed on this run** but **on the next run the channel are successfully subscribed**.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me to get rid of this exception was **using `saveEventually()` instead of `saveInBackground()`**.

Here you have [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27151459/4034572) to my answer to a similar question.

I think that `saveEventually()` is a better option because it assures that the installation will always be saved, regardless of the netwwork availability. In contrast, with `saveInBackground()` there is a chance that the save fails due to no network connectivity. Also with `saveEventually()` you don't need to do any error checking, which you should do in a `SaveCallback()` with `saveInBackground()`.

Regarding the **duplicate notifications**, this shouldn't occur if you are using the latest Parse SDK (it doesn't happen to me with 1.7.1). There was a bug that has been solved now. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24590804/4034572) and [this FB bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1520221558200050/).

Note that first time the user receives a notification after reinstalling the app, this notification can be delivered twice. It has happened to me, but only happens for the very first notification. (See the FB link for more details.) After that duplicate notification, the old installation will be removed automatically by Parse. This is my experience.

If you are trying to avoid sending duplicate notifications by implementing some logic at the CloudCode (using a beforeSave that triggers when saving a new Installation, check if the app had already been installed into the device and deleting the old installation), *don't do that!* There is not need. Parse will do it for you: it will delete the old installation :)

Answer (score 1):

I found  work around which will re-register the deleted installations in Parse again.

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (s.equals("app_Parse")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    System.out.println( "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
```

And when initializing Parse just

```
Parse.initialize(this, Constants.PARSE_APP_ID, Constants.PARSE_CLIENT_ID);

        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

//Trying  to update the current installation with a custom key and this will trigger the ParseException if this installation is not found in Installations Table in Parse Server
        String value= "Value";

        if(installation.get("customKey") != null){
            value= installation.get("customKey").toString();
        }
        installation.put("customKey", value);
//Now lets see what call back brings in
        installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Done");
                if (e == null) {
                    System.out.println("Succesfull Registration.....");
                } else {

                    System.out.println("Cleare cache");

//By clearing the cache the next time user will close and re open the app it will be installed in installations again
                    clearApplicationData();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new class and extend it with Application.
write code in this way

```
  public class BBApplication extends Application {


   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

       Parse.initialize(this, "app key", "client key");
          ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
           ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {

               @Override
               public void done(com.parse.ParseException arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if (arg0 == null) {
                         Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully    subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                    }    else {
                          Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", arg0);
                    }
            }
            });

       ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
       ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
      // Optionally enable public read access.
      // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
      ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
}
```

}

Add entry in `manifest` file

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.BBApplication"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```