# Facebook / Parse Login behaving strange: The proxied app is not already installed

Tags: java, android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

I am going nuts with this! Although, the solutions out there *did help me, they did not fix my problem.*

I am adding Facebook login to my current app. The kicker is, I have a few apps that already have this feature. I had no problem adding it to them! I have looked at the code of those apps, and this code I am working on now is identical. The only difference I can think of is this app was out on the market *then* received a Facebook login feature. But, I can't imagine that would matter...

### **Code:**

```
    Button fb = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bFacebook);
    Settings.setApplicationId(APPLICATION_ID);

    fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "BUTTON WAS PRESSED");

            ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(Arrays.asList(ParseFacebookUtils.Permissions.User.ABOUT_ME),
                    getActivity(), new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SIGNUP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LOGIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    end();
                }

                private void end() {
                    activity.changeFrag(Drawer.Frag.HOME);
                }
            });
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

### **I receive the WARNING:**

> com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: The proxied app is not already installed.

### **What happens:**

1. I click the log in button, FB app opens as it should
2. Briefly a spinner will appear.
3. FB will then promptly shut down, and my app is displayed again.

If you see my `ParseCallback` `done` code, you will notice that no matter the results of the user, it should change fragments. But this is never called, and logs are never displayed.

### **What I have Done:**

- **I have gone in to my Parse settings, and added my Secret and ID in the settings** (All the research I have done, I notice this is what a lot of people will do wrong. Check this if you are here for answers!!)
- I have added the [Facebook Sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/), using the [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers) guide.
- I have quadruple checked that my KeyHash is correct.
- I am calling `ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(APPLICATION_ID);` in my application's `onCreate`.
- I have installed the FB app
- I have tried this both on emulator and physical device
- I have COMPLETELY started over with a new project that only includes the updated Parse.jar and Facebook-sdk. STILL nothing.

**Here is a full stack trace of the warning. It did no good for me, but maybe you can decipher it:**

```
05-25 18:27:09.402    4515-4515/com.codealchemist D/Login Facebook﹕ BUTTON WAS PRESSED
com.codealchemist/com.facebook.LoginActivity: +82ms
05-25 18:27:10.002    3746-4556/com.facebook.katana W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue﹕ Exception during service
    com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: The proxied app is not already installed.
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:83)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:162)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:151)
            at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:275)
            at com.facebook.platform.auth.server.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:31)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:55)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:28)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:314)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:144)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:100)
            at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:230)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:402)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:164)
            at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:18)
            at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:40)
            at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:60)
            at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:329)
            at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:55)
            at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:258)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-25 18:27:10.002    1272-1783/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuth (has extras)} from pid 4515
05-25 18:27:10.012    3746-3817/com.facebook.katana W/Settings﹕ Setting wifi_sleep_policy has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
05-25 18:27:10.032    1272-1420/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuthDialog (has extras)} from pid 3746
05-25 18:27:10.082    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2462K, 34% free 11230K/16936K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
05-25 18:27:10.192    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:27:10.212    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
05-25 18:27:10.222    1272-1286/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuthDialog: +187ms (total +206ms)
05-25 18:27:10.292    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:27:10.592    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
05-25 18:27:10.602    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
05-25 18:27:10.612    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
05-25 18:27:10.622    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1144)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:9854F8B8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
05-25 18:27:10.672    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
05-25 18:27:10.692    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1144)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:483727B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
05-25 18:27:10.752    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
05-25 18:27:10.752    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
05-25 18:27:10.762    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/eglCodecCommon﹕ glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
05-25 18:27:10.792    3746-3746/com.facebook.katana E/eglCodecCommon﹕ **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
05-25 18:27:10.872    4515-4515/com.codealchemist W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-25 18:27:10.872    4515-4515/com.codealchemist E/HardwareRenderer﹕ An error has occurred while drawing:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The display list is not valid.
            at android.view.GLES20DisplayList.getNativeDisplayList(GLES20DisplayList.java:49)
            at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawDisplayList(GLES20Canvas.java:420)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.drawDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1646)
            at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1469)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2381)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2253)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1883)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you found a fix for this, similar problem here, driving me NUTS!

Comment: @Squeazer No i have not found a fix. All of my research lead me to believe there is a bug with parse-facebook api

Comment: @Binghammer any solution? Im getting same

Comment: @Taranfx no sorry, I never found a solution to this. I moved on to a different server rather than parse.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too.

I remove the request permission and the things back to work.

In [facebook permission guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1), in section review it said

> If your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers.
>
> The time to review your app is usually about 7 business days. Some extra-sensitive permissions, as noted below, can take up to 14 business days.

So I reduce permission to only those three permission and it is working. Maybe your problem is this.

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall the app
- Remove the the app in Facebook
- Try again

Comment: Remove the app in the Facebook Developers console?