# android parse push notification device registered multiple times

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

i am using parse push notification to  send push notifications to users of my app. I have added the code suggested in 
[Android Parse Push notification device registration only one time on one device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294181/android-parse-push-notification-device-registration-only-one-time-on-one-device)

on every unistall and then a fresh install causes my device to get registered again, bt the on updating the app simply(without uninstalling it first), the object gets updated with the help of code suggested in the link above. How do i update the same user if he/she installs the app after unistalling or atleast remove his data from my parse data