# 7 push notifications on device instead of 1

Tags: android, parse-platform

[image] [image]

As you can see from these images, it makes 7 notifications. I do not want this. Here is my code:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {


    public Application() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);

        // Initialize the Parse SDK.
        Parse.initialize(this, "yovKfUASIkl14OmRLMT5sXSJvrySDoS8MLwJ7pAA", "mnVmfBTnSzYneOxuf3jUiRKNs9P53ipsdkSwt5dq");


        // Specify an Activity to handle all pushes by default.

        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, SplashActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, apart from telling us, what have you done to debug this?

Comment: Well, i have made sure i have the latest parse version. I have also tried to make sure i have it initazled only once, and have tried it out on many devices @MikeW . Sorry that i forgot to say that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in Parse Android where duplicate installation objects are created when the app is re-installed on the same device. As a result, you see duplicate push notifications on the same device.

You can subscribe to the bug updates here,
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1520221558200050/